# Does not contain definition error for Button click event in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a button in edit.aspx page with below code

```
<asp:Button ID="GoButton" runat="server" Text="Go" onclick="GoButton_Click" />
```

then the page directive is as follows

```
<%@ Page language="c#"  EnableEventValidation="false" Codebehind="AdminHotelEdit.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="GTIAdmin.AdminHotelEdit" ValidateRequest="false"%>
```

and i have the button click event defined in code behind file as follows

```
public void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

when i debug program is getting error stating that

```
Error   146 'ASP.edit_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GoButton_Click'
and no extension method 'GoButton_Click' accepting a first argument of type
'ASP.adminhoteledit_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
assembly reference?)
```

please suggest me if you have idea about the reason of this error.

the code in edit.cs is as follows

```
namespace GTIAdmin
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AdminHotelEdit.
    /// </summary>

    public class AdminHotelEdit : GTIAdminPage
    {
        protected Button GoButton_Click;

        private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a web site project, or a web application project?

Answer (score 3):

Show us the contents of 'Edit.aspx.cs'

-- edit:

The 'inherits' field is blank. Set it to the name of the class in 'Edit.aspx.cs' and life should be good.

-- edit again:

Nope. It's because AutoEventWireup is false.

Comment: i added the contents please check it once

Comment: I really wanted to see the class name, which you've left off. Though at this point I noticed your "Inherits" field is blank. Set this to the class name; because that is the problem.

Comment: no its not blank actually it had lot of code which is unnecessry i thought .i will add it

Comment: No, THIS FIELD: 'Inherits=""' in the top part of your page.

Comment: now i posted all the code perhaps you may see some issue..thanks a lot for ur patience

Comment: So it is 'GTIAdmin.AdminHotelEdit'? That's what it should be.

Comment: Hmm. I'm at a bit of a loss to explain it. You've recompiled, obviously?

Comment: Ugh. It's because you have 'AutoEventWireup' set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Change this...

```
    protected Button GoButton_Click;
```

...to this...

```
    protected Button GoButton;
```

...to match the ID of the button in your ASPX and eliminate a name conflict with your event handler method.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

try this..

```
protected void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```