# Onclick event not working/redirecting

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is the first webservice I have made and I am having issues with my current functionality. My button in Visual Studio will only accept `OnClientClick` without the error below. My button is defined as such in my .aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Text="Search">
```

The aspx.cs file contains this:

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("www.google.com"); //just for a testing        
        }
```

The error thrown is:

> CS1061: 'ASP.main_aspx' does not contain a definition for
>   'btnSearch_Click' and no extension method 'btnSearch_Click' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'ASP.main_aspx' could be found

I have looked at various posts about `onclick` events and nothing I have tried has been the solution. Any ides on why when I click my button it doesn't redirect? Also I would like to use `OnClick` rather than `OnClient`.

Comment: `OnClientClick` call javascript function on code behind use `OnClick`

Comment: You want to use `OnClick` server-side event.

Comment: It seems as you're trying to use `OnClientClick` to call server-side code. `OnClientClick` calls client side script (javascript). If you want to do a postback you should use `OnClick` instead.

Comment: Check this question for possible solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287025/does-not-contain-definition-error-for-button-click-event-in-asp-net-page

Comment: Are you sure your aspx page uses the right .cs class as a `Page.CodeBehind`?

Comment: @Div Yes, `CodeBehind="Main.aspx.cs"`

Comment: @user5468794, change it to `CodeFile="Main.aspx.cs"`

Comment: @Div that was the issue, thank you. Would you mind answering the question for others?

Comment: @user5468794 Sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion in comment, issue is here:

```
CodeBehind="Main.aspx.cs
```

Change it to

```
CodeFile="Main.aspx.cs"
```

This will solved your error.